# Find solution to matrix sandwich product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For any two $n \times n$ real symmetric and positive definite matrices $B$ and $C$, is it always possible to find a third real symmetric and positive definite matrix $A$ such that $ABA=C$? If not, give a counter example in a $2 \times 2$ case?

Comment: Try the $2\times 2$ case yourself !